# How to achieve incremental load (SCD1) from Oracle to Parquet

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to perform SCD 1.

My watermark column is `Rma_date`. I need to use COPY activity because Oracle is not supported as Source in Dataflow in order to use Alter Row.

How to achieve SCD1 from Oracle db to parquet using COpy Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of Oracle to Parquet with what could be incremental based on your where statement, and the sink I'm making BLOB storage but Azure Data Lake is pretty much same thing:

SOURCE:

[image: Source]

SINK:

[image: Sink]

MAPPING:
Don't put anything here, it will automatically pull all columns from table and contain in Parquet.

Output Stats:

[image: Output Stats]

Parquet File sitting in Blob:

[image: Sitting]

I hope this helps, I'm not super familiar with SDC, but if things do change on the Oracle side, I know this will be reflected in the parquet since I don't have a custom mapping configured.

Comment: I have a Water mark column "DateTimeNow " , if i give that in where condition. i get data of that filter .But Day1 parquet file will be overiden by Day2. But i need like ,Append mode instead of Overide .

Comment: Ahhh there may not be an out of box solution for that. I will see

Comment: You would be best suited using the copy activity to get data from Oracle to Parquet, then using a Data Flow to merge the Parquet File to the "Permanent" Parquet file. I believe this can be achieved in Azure Data Flow. I would suggest Azure Blob Storage for these activities

Comment: This should give you an idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbDTBAyYte8